# DLL crashes IIS

Tags: iis, dll

When first executing an ISAPI DLL. the server tries to create a tmp file in w:\windows\tmp. According to Debug Diag, this is the cause of the crash.

Simple question: why is this happening???

[25/07/2015 21:15:34]
  \?\D:\Websites\xxx\xxx2.dll loaded at 0x03b90000
  C:\Windows\TEMP\en0.tmp loaded at 0x10000000
[25/07/2015 21:15:35]
  C:\Windows\TEMP\en0.tmp Unloaded from 0x10000000
  Exception 0X0EEDFADE on thread 1484.   DetailID = 1
[25/07/2015 21:15:36]

Comment: Why do you want to output to that highly restricted folder?

Comment: I don't want to output anything to the windows temp folder. The previous version of the DLL didn't output anything to c:\windows\temp and I have no idea why the new version wants to output a tmp file to anywhere.

Comment: Resolved. The en0.tmp file was a red herring and nothing to do with the crash. Tracked down the issue to a missing msvcr100.dll. Lesson learned here: always check Event Viewer properly. The error was recorded as an application popup event in the System log.

Comment: Post that as an answer and accept it please.